# PHP Regex preg_replace function finds and replaces only the first and last of 3 matches, not the middle one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following *javascript-excerpt-as-text*:

```
for (let orange of oranges) {

  for (let apple of apples) {

    for (let banana of bananas) {

      obfuscatedArray[i] = obfuscatedArray[i].split('').reverse().join('');
      obfuscatedArray[i] = window.atob(obfuscatedArray[i]);

    }

  }

}
```

from which I would like to remove the excess newlines at the bottom:

```
for (let orange of oranges) {

  for (let apple of apples) {

    for (let banana of bananas) {

      obfuscatedArray[i] = obfuscatedArray[i].split('').reverse().join('');
      obfuscatedArray[i] = window.atob(obfuscatedArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I have written this regex:

### `/(;|})(\n(\h*))+}/`

in the following PHP:

```
$myString = preg_replace('/(;|})(\n(\h*))+}/', "\$1\n\$3}", $myString);
```

but, for reasons I can't ascertain, the newline between the first closing curly brace and the second isn't being removed.

I have tested the regex in **Regex101** (ie. outside PHP's `preg_replace()` function) and it still only finds two matches instead  of three.

I really can't understand where I'm going wrong with the regex?

Comment: Your pattern matches the curly bracket before the new line and after the new line, you can't match two times the same character. (the second curly bracket).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Aha. Thank you. I was afraid it might be that. Do you know what the usual approach is when a character included in one match also needs to be included in a later match? Do I need to run the `preg_replace` in a `while` loop? Or is there a computationally less intensive alternative?

Comment: No you don't need a while loop, put the last `}` in a lookahead assertion `(?=})` (*followed by }*) that doesn't consume the character, it's only a test.

Comment: You can even do it without using a capture group: https://regex101.com/r/Z7vovK/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Ah, brilliant! Thank you. Positive and negative _lookaheads_ and _lookbehinds_ - I don't use them nearly enough. If you want to copy-paste your comment above to an answer below I will accept.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is matching the last line with the `}` and can not be matched again to take part in the next match attempt.

If you want to replace all "empty" lines in between, you change your pattern to assert a newline followed by horizontal whitespace chars to the right followed by `}` to not consume it.

```
(;|})(\n(\h*))+(?=\n\h*})
```

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSL74Q/1)

---

The pattern can also be written to using `\K` omitting the first capture group, then omit the other superfluous capture groups, a character class `[;}]` instead of an alternation and using `\R` to match any unicode newline sequence instead of only a newline:

```
[;}]\K(?:\R\h*)*(?=\R\h*})
```

In the replacement use an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CizPUA/1)

---

As you want to match all "empty" lines in between, you can replace `(?:\R\h*)*` with `\s*` shortening the pattern to:

```
[;}]\K\s*(?=\R\h*})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wSyd6X/1)

The pattern matches:

- `[;}]` Match either `;` or `}`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far (clear the current match buffer)
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?=\R\h*})` Positive lookahead, assert from the current position a newline, optional horizontal whitespace chars and `}`

Answer (score 1):

You consume (i.e. match and add matched text to the overall match memory buffer and advance the regex index) the `;` or `}` and a `}` after one or more newlines. Once a substring is consumed, the next match cannot consume the same text.

You may use lookarounds to override this:

```php
preg_replace('~([;}])\h*\R(?=\h*(?:\R\h*)+})~', '$1', $text)
preg_replace('~(?<=[;}])\h*\R(?=\h*(?:\R\h*)+})~', '', $text)
preg_replace('~[;}]\K\h*\R(?=\h*(?:\R\h*)+})~', '', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ninBNU/1) (or [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ninBNU/2)).

Note in the last two examples, there is no need to use a `$1` backreference as there is no capturing group in the pattern, it was replaced with a non-consuming lookbehind (`(?<=[;}])`) or `\K` was used to clear the current match memory buffer.

*Details*:

- `([;}])` - capturing group #1: a `;` or `}` chars
- `(?<=[;}])` - a positive lookbehind that requires `;` or `}` to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `[;}]\K` - a `;` or `}` and then the `\K` operator "loses" the text matched (the `;` or `}` are removed from the match memory buffer)
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `(?=\h*(?:\R\h*)+})` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `(?:\R\h*)+` - one or more occurrences of a line break sequence and zero or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `}` - a `}` char.